# How to override template of virtuemart user?

Tags: component, virtuemart

I am using virtuemart in joomla ! I have just develop a component named com_vip. it's working fine ! But problem is when i have to override one layout of com_virtuemart component while installing my custom component(i.e com_vip).

I can do manually by creating those files inside templates directory 
template/(templatename)/html/com_virtuemart/user/edit.php

But i have to do it, while installing my component (com_vip).
How can i do ? any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

- use script and copy that file when install your component.
- why don't you use that file in your component and extend class from VM

Comment: Can you provide examples with this or at least references to the docs on how they would "use script" or "extend class from VM"?